# How to preserve "post data" on redirect

Tags: asp.net, http, redirect, webforms

I want to redirect a post from /mynode to /eng/mynode/ and preserve form data.
I've tried "Server.Transfer" but I get an error saying "Error executing child request for /en/mynode".

I would like to implement this in a general fashion, for example in OnPreInit() method of base page.

Do you see any other options?

P.S. When you use Server.Transfer, "the page transferred to should be another .aspx page. For instance, a transfer to an .asp or .asmx page is not valid". See [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Please, explain: why is it not an answer to your question?

Comment: Server.Transfer expects an .aspx page. When I wrote Server.Transfer("~/eng/mynode") I get an error: "Error executing child request"

Comment: Yes, abhitalks's answer doesn't say you should use Server.Transfer - that's something completely different from a cross-page postback (and in fact, it wouldn't change the URL in the user's browser!). Cross-page postback allows you to get data from the previous page in the next page - so you do a cross-page postback to your destination, and it will have an instance of your current page as well. Mostly.

Comment: Also, you have to refer to the user you're responding to to give him a notification, like this: `@abhitalks: Hi, you're wrong.`

Comment: @Luaan: I would like to implement this in a general fashion, for example in OnPreInit() method of base page.

Comment: @abhitalks: thanks for the link, it's close but it doesn't answer my question. I'm not in a specific page, I'm trying to write code in a generic way, in PageBase or in other place that should handle or request to all pages.

Comment: Yeah, seeing your URL I can imagine you would. I'm affraid you might have to do it the way @OndrejSvejdar suggested. To expand a bit more on that, when the server code redirects a request (that is, changes the client side URL), it does so by sending a HTTP response with a status code of 3**, and specifying a target URL. This doesn't allow you to send any POST data (only GET data), so you have to solve this by emitting client code to your page to do the resubmit instead.

Comment: @SQLhint.com: Apart from what Luaan rightly suggested, I think you should take a look at URL Routing with ASP.NET which fully supports postback scenarios. Based on your use-case, I can see that you need to change the url from root to eng. You may start here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can write something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Response.Clear();
  Response.Write(@"<html>");
  Response.Write(@"<body>");
  Response.Write(@"<form id=""form"" action=""/eng/mynode/"" method=""post"" enctype=""application/x-www-form-urlencoded"">");
  for(int i = 0; i < Request.Form.Count; i++) {
    var key = Request.Form.GetKey(i);
    var values = Request.Form.GetValues(i);
    foreach(var value in values) {
      Response.Write(string.Format(@"<input type=""hidden"" name=""{0}"" value=""{1}"" />", key, Server.HtmlEncode(value)));
    }
  }
  Response.Write(@"</form>");
  Response.Write(@"<script>document.getElementById(""form"").submit();</script>");
  Response.Write(@"</body>");
  Response.Write(@"</html>");
}
```